# Read data from Firebase's Realtime Database and put it in an array - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I need to query the realtime database and put the result in an array.

[image]

I want to search in 'RIO DE JANEIRO - CAMPOS DOS GOYTACAZES' and in this case for the items: ELSHADAY
:.., LC GAS:... and RAPID:... in an array. In this case a array with three items.

My code to be like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
final DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

var flags = [];

read () {
  
  DBRef.child(_option).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) async {
    setState(() {
      for(var i=0; snapshot.value.*"problem")
    });
  });
}
```

On This *"problem" i can't put the length, i believe I believe that with some update the code must have changed and I don't find anything or understand it in the documentation (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/read-and-write).

Searching I found this example but I can't do the same:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTbfm.png)

I'm a student and starting in the development area, I know that I need to improve my reading of the documentation and if possible, I'll be happy not only to receive the code and leave this answer for future students here in the forum, but also to know how we'll reach the conclusion of this answer. Thank you all in advance.

Try:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
final DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

var flags = [];

consultar () {
  DBRef.ref.child(_option).limitToFirst(100);
  DBRef.child(_option).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) async {
    setState(() {
      for(var i=0; snapshot.value)
    });
  });
}
```

expected:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVbPN.png)

Comment: 1. The top of that [documentation page](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/read-and-write/) you link has a notice that it is archived, and check its updated docs on https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write 2. What is the meaning of the code in the last two screenshots you shared? If that code is *necessary* to the question, please include it as text. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by searching as follows:

```
var flags = [];

consultar (String _option) {
  DBRef.child(_option).onValue.listen((event) { 
    final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value as Map,);
    setState(() {
      data.forEach((key, value) {
      flags.add(value);
      });  
    });
  });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).